# What iOS apps allow free calling to the UK?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, voip

I travel a lot, so often rely on WiFi for calling. On the iPhone, I use [MagicJack](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/free-calls-with-magicjack/id463926997?mt=8) to get completely free calls over WiFi/VoIP to US numbers. I'm looking for a similar app to enable me to call UK numbers for free on the iPhone. Does anyone know of one?

Note:

- I'm talking only about apps that allow completely free calling to regular chargeable numbers - primarily landlines but ideally also mobiles - the Apple app stores are full of apps that allow "cheap" calling.
- Suspicious apps that require credit card numbers upfront, etc., aren't as interesting.

Comment: Unlikely to be one as in UK the person who dials the call pays and there are no free local calls - Thus the app provider must pay for the connection here

Answer (score 2):

Skype provides a free iPhone app and allows [free calls to UK freephone numbers 0800 etc](https://support.skype.com/en-us/faq/FA24/how-do-i-dial-toll-free-numbers-for-example-1-800-1-866-and-1-877-number-series). As for a service that allows totally free calls to chargeable UK numbers (either on iPhone or otherwise) for an indefinite period I can't say I have ever heard of one.

Comment: Thanks. It was chargeable numbers I was primarily interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Vonage app will do this, as long as your registered number is in the UK. During the registration you enter your number into the vonage app, it then send you a text to verify you have access to that number. Once you are registered all calls to your local country (if vonage as presence there) are free.

Comment: Which Vonage app are you referring to? Can you provide a link? The only one I can find seems restricted to calling other Vonage users.

Answer (score 0):

Phone calls are cheap enough nowadays.
There is currently no app that will give you indefinite free calls to regions such as the UK. You already benefited greatly from such a US/Canada app, don't be greedy. 2 cents or 1 cent per minute being offered by the popular apps to call UK is not going to kill you, and if you cant find one that wont give everything away for free then dont make calls then, simple :)

Comment: Downvoted. Doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

I have been using voip for quite sometime now, but i think voiphub.net is the cheapest and  they charge per second. they can also offer you free calls depending on your destination and subscription.

Comment: i agree with voiplover, www.voiphub.net is excellent.

Comment: Downvoted, doesn't answer the question - calls to the UK are not free with voiphub.net.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use Vtok or Google Voice since you can make free calls in any wifi area and you are still allowed to text!

Comment: Does this work to a UK number

Comment: Downvoted; doesn't address the question, as these don't work to the UK.

Answer (score -3):

To be honest any VoIP system, be it Skype, AIM, etc. will allow you to contact anyone else with that system for free via an internet connection.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question - I'm interested in calling phone numbers.

Answer (score -5):

Get yourself the [Yuilop](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/yuilop-speak-freely!-gratis/id426224730) app. It's free and exactly the app you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Welcome to AskDifferent. I find if a question is worth answering it is worth upvoting.  Also some instructions and a link may get you more upvotes, also please read the answer section of the [help](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help) page.

Comment: This is a badly written answer, but so far it looks promising. Yuilop requires sign-up, but otherwise does appear to be able to make free UK calls. Looking for the catch...

Comment: Turns out it was too good to be true. They give you ten free credits for calls to start off with, but then you have to pay for more. Never mind...